# Which css format is best for Magento 2 theme?

Tags: magento2, less, sass

I am aware that Magento 2 uses **Less CSS Format**, I have just one daught what if I am use **Sass CSS**?

Can anyone please answer below questions.

- What if I am using a simple CSS format?
- What are the benefits of use Sass CSS?
- Which CSS format is preferable to improve theme performance?

Thanks in advance..!